# Progress bar (Email)

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, progress-bar

I am currently developing a template email.I need to display a progress bar of this style :

```css
.progress {
    width:100px;
}
.progressleft {
    float: left;
    height: 15px;
}
.progressright {
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div style="position:relative;top: 20px; text-align:center; color:#ffffff;">50%</div>
<div style="width:250px">
<div id="prog4" class="progressleft" style="width:50%;text-align:center;background-color: #f83;"></div>
<div class="progressright" style="background-color: #ccc;"bgcolor="#ccc"></div>
```

Yet nothing appears on the receipt of the email with outlook .... But when I open the email in the browser displays all perfectly ..

Thank you in advance for your help ...

Comment: `float` does not work in email. Floats should be replaced with `align="left"` you should do some research on how to code emails, divs should be replaced with table elements and your classes should be added as attribute selectors [class=progress]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Now try to table format as like this .

```html
<table style="border:0;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="250">
<tr>
  <td bgcolor="#f83f83" style="width:50%; background-color:#f83f83; float:left; height:15px;"></td>
  <td bgcolor="#cccccc" style="width:50%; background-color:#cccccc; float:left; height:15px;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: And It is possible to make a progress bar in a circle compatible with email ?

Comment: Best option is your create a image and used to email template for across email template  and also used to table format .

Comment: why would you use float in an email? especially on a td?

Comment: because some mailer take by default td height more than you define

Comment: thank you indeed fall back on more number of images. And I displays an image depending the percentage.

Comment: And on my progress bar if I want to display the percentage of my bar milieur how I can do ?

Comment: Now you can show only static Code in mailer if you have more percentage bar than used to all images because mailer does not take any dynamic code as like javascript jquery

Comment: OK , but it is not possible to place it with a span in relative ?

Comment: Some mailer position does not support but  you can used span or div also inner in td .

Answer (score 2):

The fact is that Outlook uses Word (not IE) for rendering HTML markup of emails. All supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties are described in the following articles in MSDN:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)

Hope you will find these articles helpful.